# How to check "semi-circle" curve form?

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

We've got to int lists with X coordinates and Y coordinates of one curve. We have to check if the semi-cicle looks up or down. For the best experience[image: One is up curve? on is down]

I tried to check this with such principe
[image]
in code it's

```
 if (Array.IndexOf(listY1, listY1.Max()) != 0 & Array.IndexOf(listY1, listY1.Max()) != listX1.Length - 1)
 {
///some code
return;

}


 if (Array.IndexOf(listY1, listY1.Min()) != 0 & Array.IndexOf(listY1, listY1.Min()) != listX1.Length - 1)
 {
///some code
}
```

ye, code can be written in another way, but it will have same idea

The problem is that now all curves in some reason goes trough first check. Help plis to improve it :з
I'm debagging program with Zgraph and situation is[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear for me what does it mean "looks up" or "looks down" - is it possible to have a "look right" arc? What is about complete circle?

I suggest computing coordinates of arc's center and then having `x1, y1`, `x2, y2`, `x3, y3` and `cx, cy` decide where arc "faces" (up, down, left, right...)

```
var z1 = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;
var z2 = x2 * x2 + y2 * y2;
var z3 = x3 * x3 + y3 * y3;

var zx = (y2 - y3) * z1 + (y3 - y1) * z2 + (y1 - y2) * z3;
var zy = (x2 - x3) * z1 + (x3 - x1) * z2 + (x1 - x2) * z3;
var dz = 2 * ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y1) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x1));

var cx = -zx / dz;
var cy = zy / dz;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about comparing the following two values?

- Average value of Y coordinates of all elements in the list
- Average value of Y coordinates of several elements in the center of the list